# What does it mean for a complex-valued function to be bounded above (or below)?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I was reading about the maximum-minimum principle for harmonic functions in my lecture notes, and it was formulated like this:

> Let $\phi$ be harmonic in a simply-connected domain $D$. If $\phi$ is bounded above or below by $M$, then if for some $z_0 \in D$, $\phi (z_0) = M$, then $\phi$ is constant in $D$.

But what does it mean for complex-valued function be bounded 'above'? The complex plane has many more 'directions' than the real line. Do they simply mean 'the real part is bounded above'?

Comment: My guess is that $|\phi|\leq M$, i.e. the magnitude is bounded above. However, I'm not certain.

Comment: The statement is about *harmonic* functions, which *are* real-valued.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah, that makes a lot more sense now... Should I delete the question (since it turns out to be founded on a mistaken premise)?